# creating clustered stacked bar charts from two data frames in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am struggling with this, as I have no experience with R and just started playing with it. There are two tables that I load from two files into R. Tables have the same structure. Table 1 looks like this:

```
  SIZE   XXX   TIME-A     XXX    TIME-B   YYY   TIME-D   YYY    TIME-E  
   2     ...    59.21     ...     511.11  ...    55.31   ...     52.16
   3     ...    54.32     ...     514.31  ...    53.91   ...     56.12
   4     ...    5100.88   ...     566.9   ...    52.11   ...     545.73
```

and Table2:

```
  SIZE   XXX   TIME-A     XXX    TIME-B   YYY   TIME-D     YYY    TIME-E  
   2     ...    9.21      ...     11.11   ...    5.31      ...     2.16
   3     ...    4.32      ...     14.31   ...    3.91      ...     6.12
   4     ...    100.88    ...     66.9    ...    2.11      ...     45.73
```

I want to create a clustered stacked plot of this in R, such that TIME-A of table 1, is stacked over TIME-A of table 2, and same for TIME-B, TIME-D, and TIME-E. And then these four stacked bar be clustered according to SIZE column. So, the final outcome is to have 3 clusters each with four stacked bars as described. Now this seems to be a tough task as I am still struggling to stack two columns of two tables on each other, not saying anything about the clustering part. I am not looking for an answer (though I appreciate it so much:] ), but perhaps some links with examples will be very helpful to sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best that you bind the dataframes together and then make a faceted plot with *ggplot2*:

```
# create an 'id' variable for dataframe
d1$id <- "d1"
d2$id <- "d2"
# bind them together in one
d <- rbind(d1,d2)
# melt the result into long format
md <- melt(d, id.vars=c("id","SIZE"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(md, aes(x=SIZE, y=value, fill=id)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y", nrow=1)
```

which gives:

[image]

---

Used data:

```
d1 <- structure(list(SIZE = 2:4, TIME.A = c(59.21, 54.32, 5100.88), TIME.B = c(511.11, 514.31, 566.9), 
                     TIME.D = c(55.31, 53.91, 52.11), TIME.E = c(52.16, 56.12, 545.73)), 
                .Names = c("SIZE", "TIME.A", "TIME.B", "TIME.D", "TIME.E"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))

d2 <- structure(list(SIZE = 2:4, TIME.A = c(9.21, 4.32, 100.88), TIME.B = c(11.11, 14.31, 66.9), 
                     TIME.D = c(5.31, 3.91, 2.11), TIME.E = c(2.16, 6.12, 45.73)), 
                .Names = c("SIZE", "TIME.A", "TIME.B", "TIME.D", "TIME.E"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks Jaap. I get the following warning after calling the melt: "Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped" and the final plot is different from what you have in here.

Comment: Ok. I figured out the difference. You subset the columns to get rid-off the XXX ones, and then plotted. Thanks!

Comment: @user3639557 Sorry that i forgot to mention that I removed the XXX columns. That's indeed the trics.

Comment: @user3639557 I added the used data now.

Comment: Is it possible to have stacked bars but not in accumulative mode? Meaning, that if a=100, and b=200, the stacked version of these bars be 200 high instead of 300.

Comment: @user3639557 If you don't want them to be stacked, you can add `position="dodge"` to `geom_bar`. This will result in bars that are plotted next to each other.

Comment: I already did that. Was hoping to get a stacked-like solution for this.

Comment: @user3639557 There isn't a stacked solution for that & for good reason: what should happen when `a=200` and `b=100`?

Comment: yeah you are right. In that case an automatic reordering of the bars can be the solution.

Comment: One more question, is there a way to change the labels of the clusters? I meant the TIME.A, TIME.B, ... .

Comment: @user3639557 Change the labels in the `variable` column of your dataframe.